# vb.net / C# External handler

Tags: vb.net, handler

I have a form used to display options about processes.
When options are applyed :

**frmOptions**

```
For Each ltvi As ListViewItem In ltvProcesses.CheckedItems

     Dim proc As Process = CType(ltvi.Tag, Process)

     targeted_processes.Add(proc)
     AddHandler proc.Exited, AddressOf frmAET.a_target_process_has_been_exited
     proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True

Next
```

And in a **tools module** :

```
Public Sub a_target_process_has_been_exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        frmAET.btnStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
        msgbox("OK")

End Sub
```

And... the messagebox displays its message but the color doesn't change.
After some tries, the problem is when a_target_process_has_been_exited is actived by the handler.

If I do this (Button1 belongs to frmAET, like btnStatus) :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        a_target_process_has_been_exited()
End Sub
```

It works ! But not when I really want (when a process is ended).
So, the problem is when the sub is called by the process end event.

And when I try to specify this (maybe a frmAET's sub can modify its controls) :

```
AddHandler leproc.Exited, AddressOf frmAET.a_target_process_has_been_exited
```

Error : *Reference to a non-shared member requires an objet reference*

Could you help me ?

Comment: The `Exited` event is raised in a thread other than the UI Thread. You need to `BeginInvoke` a Control in the UI Thread or use the [Process.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject) to set the object (it could be the Form that contains the Button) delegate to marshal the event handler calls back to the UI Thread.

Comment: The `frmAET` reference is however unknown, here. The event handler should be in `frmOptions`, where the `frmAET` *existence* is checked before trying to change any of its Controls' properties.

Comment: @Jimi
Thanks. I tried a lot of things but impossible to make it work.

I have 2 forms (frmAET & frmOptions) and 1 module, I use addhandler in frmOption but this form is closed when options are applied. frmAET is the main form which stays visible all the time.

But, as I need to use addhandler in a form which does no longer exist, I have to AddressOf a module's sub (can't use "AddressOf frmAET.sub").

Since the module's sub, I would like to modify the frmAET.btnStatus.ForeColor

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Create the Process in the Module then, so you can keep it alive until it exits. Remember to `.Dispose()` of it, if not null, in the `Exited` event.

Comment: @Jimi Ill try this but I have no experience with threads. Processes what I check the end are like notepad and may be created before the app launch.

Comment: You don't need any experience with threads for this. If, as already mentioned, you set the Process' `SynchronizingObject`, you can just directly set the property of a Control which is the Sync object itself or a child of it. If you're not using a Sync object for some reason, in the event handler `BeginInvoke` the Control using a `MethodInvoker`:  `BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() [Some Control].ForeColor = Color.Red`. I suggest you use the first pattern, setting the Sync object to the Form that contains the Control you want to change.

Comment: @Jimi Done ! ` AddHandler proc.Exited, AddressOf a_target_process_has_been_exited
proc.SynchronizingObject = frmAET
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True` Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AddHandler` seems to use AddressOf ***frmAET***.a_target_process_has_been_exited, that means method in frmAET form itself. Not tools module as you stated.

Let's consider your frmOptions is correct and frmAET is containing this (with removed explicit reference to frmAET, since it's local)

```
Public Sub a_target_process_has_been_exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    btnStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
    MsgBox("OK")
End Sub
```

As comments already explained, your event handler is called in another thread and you need to sync yourself to main UI thread. For example like this:

```
Public Sub a_target_process_has_been_exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() HandleProcessExit())
End Sub

Public Sub HandleProcessExit
    btnStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
    MsgBox("OK")
End Sub
```

This version will block main UI thread until you click on the MsgBox button.

You should add some Try/Catch block. Exception in another threads are difficult to detect otherwise.

This code depends on implicit form instances that VB.NET creates for you. I expect your frmAET is actually My.Forms.frmAET instance to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, this works very well ! My problem was the correct syntax of Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() HandleProcessExit()) Thanks you !

Comment: @VisualVincent Done